# F# task expression not being executed, how to start the task?

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

I'm setting up a new F# API project and I'm new to F#.
I've created a custom `AuthorizationHandler` and decorated the `WeatherForeCastController` with it.

However, the task expression in my handler is not executed and API returns 500 error. What am I doing wrong?

```
type AuthorizeMyRequirement () = 
    interface IAuthorizationRequirement

type public MyHandler (repository: IAuthorizationRepository) =
    inherit AuthorizationHandler<AuthorizeMyRequirement>()

    override this.HandleRequirementAsync(context, requirement): Task = 
        match context.Resource with
                   | :? HttpContext as httpContext -> 
                        let somevalue = httpContext.GetRouteValue("somevalue") :?> string // Breakpoint is hit
                        task {
                            let! modules = repository.ListModules(somevalue) // Breakpoint is not hit. Task is apparently not getting started. How to start it?
                            if (modules.Any(fun m -> m = "MODULE X")) 
                                then context.Succeed(requirement)
                                else context.Fail()
                        }
                   | _ -> 
                        context.Fail()
                        Task.CompletedTask
```

If I replace the task expression with a straightforward `context.Succeed(requirement)` and return a `Task.CompletedTask` the API method works fine

```
type AuthorizeMyRequirement () = 
    interface IAuthorizationRequirement

type public MyHandler (repository: IAuthorizationRepository) =
    inherit AuthorizationHandler<AuthorizeMyRequirement>()

    override this.HandleRequirementAsync(context, requirement): Task = 
        match context.Resource with
                   | :? HttpContext as httpContext -> 
                        let somevalue = httpContext.GetRouteValue("somevalue") :?> string
                        context.Succeed(requirement)
                        Task.CompletedTask // All breakpoints hit up to here, controller proceeds to WeatherForeCastController and returns data
                   | _ -> 
                        context.Fail()
                        Task.CompletedTask
```

So my question is, if I have `task { ... }`, how do I ensure the task actually gets started?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I hadn't managed to bootstrap NLog. Finally managed and turns out there's a TaskCanceledException inside the repository inside `ListModules` call. I don't understand why my breakpoint wouldn't hit the exact line that fails. So the question becomes: Why is the breakpoint not hit?

Comment: You can force a breakpoint by calling `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` in your code. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't managed to bootstrap NLog. Finally managed and turns out there's a TaskCanceledException inside the repository inside ListModules call.

That the breakpoint isn't being hit has nothing to do with the execution, call inside `task {}` was being exeucted but threw an exception.